# idea IDEA and play framework: always download jar.

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I created some play app using activator command. and command line, I could run the app. But after I run idea command to create an idea project, after open it using IDEA, when trying to run it, it trying to download jar file. Since both activator and IDEA are using sbt, which in turn using ivy to manage jar file. Why idea tries to download jar file? Any setting to let it to use the jar files already downloaded by activator?

Comment: *Which* jar is it downloading repeatedly?

Comment: I didn't check the jar name. I simply wants it to stop downloading any jar. I want to use IDEA to edit, and then use SBT to do compile. How to stop the background job? I stopped it but it doesn't work, it locked the ivy lock file.